# How to get the cookie accepted and read the name of restaurants using beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using the following python code, but it does not allow me to get beyond the cookies

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-637ca4cb-0a1f492e332bb59f0bc53de4"}

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/FindRestaurants?geo=155019&diets=10697&establishmentTypes=10591&minimumTravelerRating=TRAVELER_RATING_MEDIUM&broadened=false"


# Make a request to the website
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the HTML content with Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

The soup extracted in this way does not contain the elements I need to extract, e.g. name of restaurants in this case. It seems the cookie is blocking to read the html page. Please suggest how to extract the soup and find elements from it.

Comment: tripadvisor uses JS  request and renders data from api. You can only get data from source page (hit `Ctrl+U` in browser) using requests. Fortunately, for tripadvisor you can search for xhr in network tap and grab cURL. There are plenty of videos and blogs showing tutorials for that, you can google if you don't know how to search for xhr and cURL and convert to python code.

Comment: To use cookies you can do `session = requests.Session()` and use `session` just like `requests` like `session.get(url, headers=HEADERS)`